# What is the probability of drawing three cards, twice in a row, and having both results be any same suit set in a 53 card deck (52+joker)

Tags: probability, card-games

I found that the probability of drawing three cards and have them be of the same suit i.e. HHH, DDD, CCC,SSS from a 53 card deck (one joker included) is $(52/53)*(12/52)*(11/51)=0.048835$

I want to find the probability of drawing any two suit sets in a row.
I believe I would find the probability of drawing the same suit set as before and add the probability of drawing any of the other three possible suit sets.

Is the probability of drawing another same set as the previous suit $10/50*9/49*8/48 = .006122$ ?

If so then do I add that to the probability of it instead being any of the other suit sets $39/50*12/49*11/48=0.043776$

$.006122+.043776=0.049898$ This doesn't make sense to me since the probability would be higher than drawing just the first suit set.

I can calculate the independent probability of drawing two suit sets in a row as $((52/53)*(12/52)*(11/51))^2=0.002385$ so I feel common sense says the dependent probability should be higher than this value but lower than drawing a single suit set.

Comment: Note that you first took 3 cards **and** then took another 3 cards, so you should multiply the probability you computed first, with the probability of picking another set of cards. That probability is indeed higher than the one you computed when you place the 3 cards back.

Comment: Yes, as @Student points out, it seems that you are confusing 'sampling with replacement' and 'sampling without replacement.'  Could you clarify in the question if "twice in a row" means that you do not replace the first three cards?  Or do you put the three cards back and shuffle the deck again?

Comment: In my example I would draw three cards, have them be all of the same suit, discard them, then draw another three cards and have them be the same suit. Thanks!

Comment: Then you should multiply the probabilities you computed.

Comment: If joker drawn does it count as any suit, or not count as any suit, or what?

Comment: A joker drawn would "ruin" the combo and would not count as a suit. Unfortunately I can't edit the comment I made earlier but what I meant to say when I draw the second set of three cards it can be any suit set i.e. I draw three cards and they are all hearts, discard, draw another three and have them be three spades, hearts, clubs, or diamonds. Thanks!